# Real error message not available with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

When using Alamofire, I don't get back the real error message that the server sends. Instead I get back something like this:

```
po debugPrint(error.description)
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 413" UserInfo={StatusCode=413, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 413}
```

How do I know what the actual error is, and why doesn't Alamofire just return the actual error message?